# What is the estimated regression surface

Tags: statistics, regression

A table is given the data: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0nhF.png)

Based on this table, we computed

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i1}^2 = 471$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i2}^2 = 163.84$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i1}X_{i2} = 235$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i1}Y_i = 4915.3$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i2}Y_i = 3103.66$

We consider the following model involving both independent variables and an intercept: $$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i1} + \beta_2X_{i2} + \epsilon_i$$

where $\beta_j, j = 0,1,2$ are $3$ parameters and $\epsilon_i$ are pairwise indepedent random errors with mean $0$ and common variance $\sigma^2$. In the matrix notation, the model is

$$Y = X \beta + \epsilon$$

$$ X=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 7 & 2.6\\
1 & 1 & 2.9\\
1 & 11 & 5.6\\
1 & 11 & 3.1\\
1 & 7 & 5.2\\
1 & 11 & 5.5\\
1 & 3 & 7.1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ Y=
\begin{bmatrix}
78.5 \\
74.3 \\
104.3 \\
87.6 \\
95.9 \\
109.2 \\
102.7 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The least square estimator of $\hat\beta$ of $\beta$ is

$\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y =
\begin{bmatrix}
51.7 \\
1.5 \\
6.6 
\end{bmatrix}
$

question:

(a) write the estimated regression surface and interpret each regression coefficient in the context of the data

How do I do that? I have calculated most of $(X'X)$, $(X'X)^{-1}$, $X'Y$. But not sure how to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The regression surface is given by

$$\hat{y}=51.7+1.5x_1+6.6x_2.$$

If you [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3D51.7%2B1.5*x%2B6.6*y) this bivariate function (independent variables: $x_1$ and $x_2$; dependent variable: $\hat{y}$) you will get something similar to this surface

[image]

The coefficients can be interpreted in the following way.

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are zero then the output is given by the intercept/bias $51.7$ units, which is the coefficient $\beta_0$. If you only increase $x_1$ by one unit, then the output will increase by $1.5$ units, this is the coefficient $\beta_1$. And if you only increase $x_2$ by one unit, then the output will increase by $6.6$ units, this number is the coefficient $\beta_2$.